# How do I use Variable Values Stored Within Variable Values as function arguments?

Tags: php

I'm trying to gather all function arguments within a single variable so I can use the single variable instead of entering all arguments into the function.

Below is what I've done so far to try to achieve this and it hasn't been successful.

Variable that stores all variable values together:

```
$bindargs = "$var1, $var2, $var3";
```

Function which I am trying to pass above variable as 3 separate arguments:

```
function($bindargs);
```

I want above to run the same as below:

```
function($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Comment: Create `$bindargs` as an array and not a string.  Using a string can cause all sorts of problems and using an array is simpler.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple

Answer (score 1):

Solution: by using array

`$bindargs = array('var1'=>$var1,'var2'=>$var2,'var3'=>$var3);`

now pass this $bindargs to the function and use like this

```
function functionname($bindargs){

$var1 = $bindargs['var1'];
$var2 = $bindargs['var2'];
$var3 = $bindargs['var3'];
// now you can use your logic to perform the action on the variables which you want
}
```

Comment: right that's why i just removed that solution

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose you could do something like this, with an array:

```
<?php

function func($a, $b, $c) {
    echo $a."\n";
    echo $b."\n";
    echo $c."\n";

}

$bindargs = ['a','b','c'];
func(...$bindargs);
```

I don't see why you'd want to. You lose type hinting on your arguments, and named arguments, and this all seems to me like a way just to obfuscate the code and make it difficult for whoever comes after you.

Comment: "bind" suggests the usage tho